# Inject .NET Core object as singleton instance-per-type?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Is it possible using .NET Core dependency injection to have distinct types resolve their own singleton? For example, a transient type resolves in it's constructor a distinct singleton. Even a singleton type in their constructor would resolve to it's own distinct singleton. It is similar to an injected static member on the class type.

HttpClientFactory kind of does this with HttpClient. The HttpClient is disposable but the underlying message handler is a lifetime controlled object for the owner. How could I replicate that?

Ideally the solution wouldn't involve me knowing all types being injected into a constructor -- for example HttpClientFactory does not have that requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question and describe *what* the underlying problem is you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else is interested in the future, I solved this by exploiting generics. For example:

```
public interface IStaticMember<TOwner, TValue>
    where TOwner : class
    where TValue : class
{
    public TValue Value { get; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class StaticMember<TOwner, TValue> : IStaticMember<TOwner, TValue>
    where TOwner : class
    where TValue : class
{
    public StaticMember(TValue value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public TValue Value { get; private set; }
}
```

Registration methods...

```
public static IServiceCollection AddStaticMember<TOwner, TValue>(
    this IServiceCollection @this)
    where TOwner : class
    where TValue : class
{
    return @this.AddSingleton<IStaticMember<TOwner, TValue>, StaticMember<TOwner, TValue>>();
}

public static IServiceCollection AddStaticMember<TOwner, TValue>(
    this IServiceCollection @this,
    Func<IServiceProvider, TValue> valueFactory)
    where TOwner : class
    where TValue : class
{
    return @this.AddSingleton<IStaticMember<TOwner, TValue>>(serviceProvider =>
    {
        return new StaticMember<TOwner, TValue>(valueFactory(serviceProvider));
    });
}
```

Classes which use it...

```
public class OwningClass1 : IOwningClass1
{
    public OwningClass1(IStaticMember<IOwningClass1, IMyStatic> myStatic) { ... }
}

public class OwningClass2 : IOwningClass2
{
    public OwningClass2(IStaticMember<IOwningClass2, IMyStatic> myStatic) { ... }
}
```

And injecting a static onto a transient (two ways)...

```
services.AddTransient<IOwningClass1, OwningClass1>();
services.AddTransient<IOwningClass2, OwningClass2>();
services.AddTransient<IMyStatic, MyStatic>();
services.AddStaticMember<IOwningClass1, IMyStatic>();
services.AddStaticMember<IOwningClass2, IMyStatic>();

// or

services.AddTransient<IOwningClass1, OwningClass1>();
services.AddTransient<IOwningClass2, OwningClass2>();
services.AddStaticMember<IOwningClass1, IMyStatic>(serviceCollection => new MyStatic());
services.AddStaticMember<IOwningClass2, IMyStatic>(serviceCollection => new MyStatic());
```

In both cases, all instances of OwningClass1 get the same instance, and all instances of OwningClass2 get another distinct instance.

Please let me know if there is a better way.